# javascript inside <% %> brackets

Tags: javascript

I'm using some code I found online but want to understand it better. Works fine but I'm going to need to modify it. What does it mean that much of the js is enclosed in <% %> brackets? Code follows:

```js
        <% AllNetLabs.App_Code.GeoHelper helper1 = new AllNetLabs.App_Code.GeoHelper();
            foreach (var item in helper1.GetSpatialData())
            { %>
                geometries.push('<%=item %>');
        <%  } %>
        <% AllNetLabs.App_Code.GeoHelper helper2 = new AllNetLabs.App_Code.GeoHelper();
            foreach (var item in helper2.GetAttributeData())
            { %>
                attributes.push('<%=item %>');
        <%  } %>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to where you found that code?

Comment: this looks .net and its a razor syntax means gets evaluated on server side

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript inside those brackets at all.  Looks more like C#.  You might want to double-check where you got this code, as well as what exactly you mean by "works fine".  This would most certainly *not* work as JavaScript.

Comment: And frankly, the code is...not ideal. Using a loop to generate a bunch of `push` statements...

Comment: Basically this either isn't JavaScript(likely) and if it IS JavaScript, it's templated by the library/script you're using, so we can't help you without further information.

Comment: OK. It is <script> from the top of my .aspx so it must be the way you interface between js and .aspx. I thought it was all js but it must be a way to call c# code from Js. I cache geometry and attributes in c# and this reads it in js so I can display values in an alert popup. Many Thanks everyone!

Comment: Also, this is where I found the original reference related to OpenLayers: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-features-with-text.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the code in the <% %> blocks is a different language (C#?). Typically, this pattern is used to prepopulate javascript with some values server-side and I would guess that's what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean EJS?
http://www.embeddedjs.com/
Example for the site:

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: foreach is not a JavaScript loop.

Answer (score -1):

They're using dynamic data from the server to push into a JS array.

Comment: @FranVerona This *is* an answer to the question.  If you don't think that it's a sufficiently *useful* answer to the question, you can reflect that opinion by downvoting it, but that doesn't mean it's not an answer.